# Probability of event after time $t$ : why the second derivation doesn't work?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following probabilistic event :

I have an atom that can emit a single photon. **I want to compute** the probability that this photon is emitted at time $t$.

**I know** the probability to emit a photon in $[t;t+dt]$ knowing that no photon was emitted before. I call this probability $w(t)dt$.

I consider time $0$ as the beginning of my process.

I define :

$p(t)dt$ : probability that the photon is emitted in $[t;t+dt]$.

$w(t)dt$ : probability to emit the photon in $[t;t+dt]$ knowing that no photon has been emitted before.

$a(t)$ : probability that no photon has been emitted in $[0;t]$.

I have :

$$p(t)dt=w(t)dt.a(t) $$

To compute $p(t)$, I can do :

---

First method, the one that works :

$$a(t+dt)=(1-w(t)dt).a(t)$$

Indeed, the probability to have no photon emitted at $t+dt$ is equal to the probability that no photon has been emitted during $[t;t+dt]$ knowing no photon has been emitted before $t$, mutliplied by probability of no photon emitted before $t$.

And I have a differential equation on $a$ :

$$ \frac{da}{dt}(t)=-w(t).a(t)$$

I solve this equation, and I can find $p(t)$.

---

Second method : the one that doesn't work

I have :

$$a(t)=(1-w(t-dt)dt)a(t-dt)$$

Indeed, the probability to have no photon emitted at $t$ is equal to :

No photon emitted in $[t-dt;t]$ knowing no photon has been emitted before $t-dt$, mutliplied by probability to have no photon emitted before $t-dt$.

Then, I can do a recursion :

$$a(t)=(1-w(t-dt)dt)(1-w(t-2dt)dt)...(1-w(0)dt)$$

But this method doesn't allow me to find $a(t)$. For example I don't have any dt on the left, and the only 0 order in dt on the right is $1$...

Where am I wrong in this second method and is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Take log to both sides of the last (approximate) equality and notice that the resulting expression is simply a Riemann sum approximating the integral $-\int_{0}^{t}w(t-s)\,\mathrm{d}s$.

Answer (score 1):

The second is also right, only slighly less straightforward. Take logarithms and then

$$ \log a(t)  = \sum_{k=0}^{t/dt} \log(1- w( k \, dt) dt) \tag{1} $$

Now, recall that $\log(1-x) \approx -x$ for small $x$, so in the limit

$$ \log a(t)  = \sum_{k=0}^{t/dt} - w( k \, dt) dt = -\int_0^t w(t') dt' \tag{2}  $$

This is the integral equation version of your differential equation

$$ \frac{da(t)}{dt}=-w(t).a(t) \tag{3}$$

Indeed, you can check that deriving $(2)$ one gets $(3)$.